# Как удалить записи wordpress через mysql команду

Tags: mysql, wordpress

На сайте необходимо удалить все записи, где автор не админ. 
Как это сделать?
Пробовал так:

```
DELETE * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_author`>1
```

но это не работает

Comment: как не работает? что пишет? какая инфа хранится в `post_author`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синтаксис команды `delete`:

```
DELETE FROM Table_Name Where ....
```

В вашем случае:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_author` > 1;
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Виктор не удивляйся, когда после такого начнутся "глюки" на сайте. Нельзя так лазить в базу ВП. Нужно использовать АПИ или готовые плагины.

Answer (score 2):

> На сайте необходимо удалить все записи, где автор не админ. Как это
>   сделать? Пробовал так:

Никогда!!! Запомни НИКОГДА не трогай базу ВП напрямую. Для всего в ВП есть [API](https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:API_WordPress) / [функции](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC). В частности для удаление постов есть [`wp_delete_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).
В крайнем случае класс [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/ru:wpdb_Class), но для данной задачи он и не нужен.

Проще и правильнее для таких разовых операций использовать готовые плагины, коих великое множество https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=bulk+delete

**Добавка**. А если авторов не несколько десятков, а удаляемых постов не тысячи, то может быть быстрее удалить вручную через админку.