# Добавить заглавную картинку Wordpress через СУБД

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Доброе время суток. Есть сайт на WP, доступ к upload и Mysql. Нужно через БД прописывать заглавные картинки к постам. Добавление записи в таблицу wp_postmeta для _wp_attached_file результатов не дает. Сами файлы заливаю по ФТП. В чем может быть косяк? В правах на ФТП - что WP не может туда залезть, так как файлы создаются от имени другого пользователя? Или в чем то еще - прописать нужно ссылку еще где-то?

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно через БД прописывать заглавные картинки к постам

[Не нужно так даже думать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794763/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-wordpress-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-mysql-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83/795053#795053). Нужно использовать API/готовые плагины если нужно массовость.

> В правах на ФТП - что WP не может туда залезть, так как файлы
>   создаются от имени другого пользователя?

Медиатка в ВП - это не файлы на хостинге. Это куча записей в базе. И имеено оттуда выбирается изображение записи (то, что ты назвал "заглавная картинка")

Comment: К сожалению, заказчик отвергает плагины. Инструментарий по заполнению на С# и SQL. Естественно, по поводу кучи записей в курсе. Я их раскидал, файлы закачал, посты добавляются нормально. Трабл только с картинками. API добавления изображения можно дернуть POST или GET запросом? От PHP довольно далек, работаю с данными (DTS)

Comment: @kamakama да. ночью вспомнил - есть же ещё [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/). Сосбно, это тоже АПИ. И [REST-API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) если речь о стороих приложениях