# Какой правильный синтаксис написания SQL запросов?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

В разных мануалах встречаю разное написание SQL запросов. А именно использование ` и '.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `my_sql_table` where surname='Сидоров'"; 
$query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM my_sql_table WHERE link_id = 10");
```

Или второй способ написания (именно акцент на ` '), свойственен только WP? 
Не смог найти ответа в поисковике, если не трудно, распишите в двух словах или тыкните носом в ссылку =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ

> `

это "обратный апостроф", он используется в `SQL` запрос для всех внутренних имен, чтобы экранировать их от каких-то внутренних значений, или выражений, например у нас есть таблица `join` если мы напишем запрос формата `SELECT * FROM join` у нас будет ошибка, потом что оно подумает что мы пытаемся использовать зарезервированное выражение `JOIN` для выборки данных, а не таблицу `join`, по этому существуют обратные апострофы, чтобы экранировать пользовательские имена от выражений. Написав запрос так(заместо троеточия второй обратный апостроф)

> SELECT * FROM `join...

Запрос сработает без ошибок, и выборка будет из нашей таблицы `join`.

Обычные апострофы(их часто называют одинарными кавычками, это не верно)

> '

служат нам в `SQL` запрос для тех же целей что и обратные, только мы выделяем не имена, а значения, например есть запрос формата `SELECT * FROM teest WHERE t = join`, этот запрос не сработает потому что в условии, мы будто применили выражение `JOIN`, по этому нам надо экранировать его таким образом `SELECT * FROM teest WHERE t = 'join'` и ошибки не будет, проще говоря, обычные апострофы говорят `SQL` "это просто строка, не выражение".

Кстати пример, когда мы пишем ответ комментарий или вопрос на Stack Overflow, мы используем обратные апострофы для выделения каких-то функций или технологий, почти тоже самое происходит и в `SQL`.

Comment: Можно только добавить, что к WordPress этот синтаксис отношения не имеет.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а по WP есть какие то нюансы по синтаксису SQL?

Comment: Нет, WP просто использует MySQL

Comment: Совершено верно, это синтаксис `SQL`, к `WP` Он не имеет никакого отношения, просто `WP` Правильно использует запросы.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, нет. В ВП вообще ненужно (нельзя) лазить в базу [никакими SQL запросами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794763/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-wordpress-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-mysql-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83/795053#795053) в 99% случаев.

Comment: Ну так используется встроеные функции для выборки например в плагинах, не панекуйте так. :)