# Посчитать количество строк sql запроса в WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Как в WordPress можно посчитать количество строк sql запроса?
Знаю, что можно сделать Select и потом $wpdb->num_rows
Но если никакие данные в выборке не нужны, можно просто узнать количество строк? Или нужно всегда делать выборку любого значения для подсчёта?

Comment: делать $wpdb->num_rows - кажется лишним, чем не угодил SELECT COUNT(*), какой нибудь? Ну и да, это не имеет отношения к пхп и вордпресу, ваш вопрос чисто по sql.

Comment: Вопрос о чем? О вашем кастомном запросе, или о запросе, формируемом WordPress по WP_Query? Если второе, то там запрос на полстраницы, и он возвращает число строк всегда

Comment: @test123 Вот как раз про SELECT COUNT(*) и не знал, спасибо =).

Comment: @test123, если вопрос касается ВП, то не нужно вредных советов как  лазить в базу. Хорошо, данный подсчёт ничего страшного не натворит и может даже выдаст правильный результат (что вряд ли. но возможно), но в общем случае - не нужно.

Comment: @SeVlad, >>не нужно вредных советов как лазить в базу<< о_О, это не вредный совет, а документация по SQL. Или "как объявить поле" в ООП для вас тоже вредный совет? Если фрамемворк использующий SQL способен как то поломать базу или выполняя документированный код, описанный стандартом, прийти к другому варианту, который этому стандарту не соответствует, по вашему, виноваты "вредные советы"?

Comment: @test123 при работе с ВП в 99% случаев вообще не нужно и [НЕЛЬЗЯ трогать базу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794763/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-wordpress-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-mysql-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83/795053#795053). А там, где реально нужно - как раз нужно использовать класс [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/ru:wpdb_Class)

Comment: @test123  >Если фрамемворк использующий SQL.... виноваты "вредные советы"? <<< поставим вопрос по другому - если лазая напрямую в базу можно поломать САЙТ - это не вредный совет? И дело не в синтаксисе, а в принципах работы с движком.

Comment: @SeVlad, Вы меня пугаете... если человек лезит в базу напрямую - значит он знает что делает. Убить базу можно и через wpdb. Это не делает плохим ни тот ни другой вариант.

Comment: @test123 >значит он знает что делает. 
<<< Ой, не факт. такой не факт что просто ужас :) Уже сам тот факт, что кто-то лезет в базу (те в обход движка) - как правило говорит о том, что он не знает ВП. За ОЧЕНЬ редким исключением Очень-очень редким. Но знающий не будет спрашивать на SO/формах про синтаксис :) Как-то так.

Comment: @SeVlad То-есть по вашему мнению "ЗНАЮЩИЕ" они сверхлюди и такими рождаются? Как тогда научиться и узнать, если не спрашивать то, что не понимаешь? Да и про БД и WP. Почему туда не нужно лезть? Если БД есть, и есть возможность с ней работать, с ней надо работать. Или, по вашей логике, надо довольствоваться тем, что имеешь?

Comment: @Gagablik по нашей логике нужно уметь пользоваться документацией . А если не знаешь как сделать правильно - спрашивать. Спрашивать именно как правильно решать ЗАДАЧУ, а не придумав ПУТЬ решения спрашивать почему оно не работает.

Comment: @SeVlad Я знал как сделать. Спросил как сделать рациональней. Я не спрашивал почему не работает

Comment: Если бы знал как делать ПРАВИЛЬНО - в вопросе и метках вообще не было слова "SQL" (да и "php" - лишнее) . А ты даже не понял ни глубину вопроса  @KAGGDesign-а, ни о чем я говорил, ни ссылки не смотрел...

Comment: @SeVlad Почему не должно быть меток? sql запрос, который пишется на php, при помощи функций WordPress. Прямых запросов к базе я не использовал, создавал через фукнции WP. Ссылку прочитал и не понял, почему это мне нельзя в своей БД что-то делать. У меня отдельная БД для этого создана и храню данные, которые нельзя добавить в БД WP. Мне казалось не рациональным делать выборку из БД каких то данных, если мне только нужно узнать количество строк. Именно это я и спросил. ничего более