# У записи вордпресс нет категории

Tags: wordpress

Записи на Вордпресс-блоге сохранились без категории после сохранения записи в базу данных с помощью стороннего парсера. Вместо категории - пусто, даже не категория "Без рубрики", а пустота.

То есть выглядит вот так "Рубрика:  Автор:  ", а не вот так, например, "Рубрика: Без категории  Автор: Администратор ".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать запрос в базу данных, чтобы присвоить записям хотя бы какую-нибудь рубрику, например "Без категории"?

Comment: После чего "сохранились"? Где "пусто"? Отредактируй вопрос. И метка `php` тут не нужна

Comment: После сохранения записи в базу данных с помощью стороннего парсера.Пусто значит выглядит вот так "Рубрика:  Автор:  ", а не вот так, например, "Рубрика: Без категории  Автор: Администратор ".

Comment: Напиши это в вопросе

Comment: написал........

Answer (score 0):

> и после сохранения записи в базу данных с помощью стороннего парсера.

В этом и проблема. Парсер пишет напрямую в БД, в обход функций ВП. Таким образом он поломал связи, базу.

См [Как удалить записи wordpress через mysql команду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794763/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-wordpress-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-mysql-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83/795053#795053)

Посты нужно вставлять с использованием `wp_insert_post`.

Теперь я бы рекомендовал восстановить из бекапа, а если невозможно - удалить все кривое. Естественно, не запросами в базу, а функциями ВП/плагинами. (Впрочем, в данном случае, если вычленить из парсера кривые запросы, то можно на их основе написать "удалятор").

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что нельзя в таблице постов базы данных присвоить какой-нибудь ячейке значение, которое присваивало бы записи какую-нибудь рубрику. 

То есть нельзя, к примеру, к записи "Виды деревьев" присвоить рубрику "Лес" отправив запрос в базу данных?

Comment: А как узнать название ячейки, которое отвечает за рубрику поста?

Comment: Теоретически можно, но кроме рубрики в базу пишется ещё много разных связей, создаются ключи и тп. Это не исправит, а только усугубит положение

Comment: Cм https://codex.wordpress.org/Database%20Description

Comment: "Посты нужно вставлять с использованием wp_insert_post." а если их несколько сотен тысяч?

Comment: @alenkins да хоть миллион - в базу лазить нельзя, нужно использовать АПИ ВП.

Comment: @SeVlad нормально импортировали в БД 800 тыс. записей sql-запросом, после чего сайт уже третий год работает без сюрпризов и проблем с обслуживанием. Я вот сейчас не очень представляю как бы это всё штатными средствами WP импортировалось и сколько бы заняло времени

Comment: @alenkins, а я считал. что Вы знаете структуру БД, понимаете, о ключах-связях и что они создаются во время импорта. :( То что вы не видите проблем на вашем сайте вовсе не значит что их нет/не возникнут и уж тем более то, что их не будет у др. юзеров (вот вопрос ТС-са - типичнейшая проблема.). И ещё про  wp-cli  почитайте если работаете с такими объёмами данных.. Да и вообще полезная штука.

Comment: @SeVlad так что мешает-то создать все необходимые связи? вы так пишете как будто структуру бд вордпресса держат в строжайшей тайне от простых смертных. 800 тысяч записей это не большой объём данных

Comment: @alenkins просто потому что это не возможно сделать 3-4мя SQ:-запросами в один проход.. Я бы Вам рассказал эти азы, но.. не в комментах SO. Тем более что Вы проигнорировали  мою давнюю простую просьбу.